# How to convert local timestamp (of a given time zone) to UTC?

Tags: postgresql

I am working in a code where multiple time zones will be available. I need to create a function which takes the selected local timestamp as well as the local time zone. The return value of the function should the UTC time of the local time (local time for the given local time zone).

I am working on PostgreSQL 8.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT Now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
```

This will return `timestamp without time zone` at specified time zone (UTC in my example) for given `timestamp with time zone`.

From PostgreSQL [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-datetime.html):

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40' AT TIME ZONE 'MST';
Result: 2001-02-16 19:38:40-08

SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2001-02-16 20:38:40-05' AT TIME ZONE 'MST';
Result: 2001-02-16 18:38:40
```

You can get list of time zones from `pg_timezone_names`:

```
select * from pg_timezone_names limit 5

name;abbrev;utc_offset;is_dst
----------------------
PRC;CST;08:00:00;f
Asia/Brunei;BNT;08:00:00;f
Asia/Ujung_Pandang;CIT;08:00:00;f
Asia/Ust-Nera;VLAT;11:00:00;f
Asia/Phnom_Penh;ICT;07:00:00;f
```